# Azure subdomains with different solutions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have 3 different MVC solutions:

Customers site

Admin site

Businesses site

---

i wish to have them as:

www.mysite.com

admin.mysite.com

business.mysite.com

---

How can this be achieved in Azure?

Thanks

Comment: How are you deploying the sites: individual websites, individual cloud services, a single cloud service or hosted on a VM?

Comment: was planning for individual websites

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions at [Configuring a custom domain name for an Azure Web Site](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/).  More generally, create your Azure websites and then create three CNAME records with your domain registrar and point them to the Azure DNS:

- create CNAME record "www" and point to www-mysite.azurewebsites.net
- create CNAME record "admin" and point to admin-mysite.azurewebsites.net
- create CNAME record "business" and piont to business-mysite.azurewebsites.net

Then in the Azure Portal on each website - Manage Domains - to add the custom domain.